# How can I filter by more than one user pattern in TFS API?

Tags: tfs

I have the following code:

```
var tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(TFS_SERVER_URL));    
tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

var query = GetQuery(...)
var identities = ims.ReadFilteredIdentities(query, 5000, null, true, (int)MembershipQuery.None);
foreach (var item in identities.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20} {2}", item.DisplayName, item.UniqueName, item.GetAttribute("Mail", null));
}
```

Now, when query is something like

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.Type == 'User' AND (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.DisplayName CONTAINS 'alice' OR Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.DisplayName CONTAINS 'bob')
```

The code throws the following exception:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.IdentityExpressionException: TF400819: Query Expression is not well-formed 
---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: TF400819: Query Expression is not well-formed
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.IdentityManagementWebService2.ReadFilteredIdentities(String expression, Int32 suggestedPageSize, String lastSearchResult, Boolean lo
okForward, Int32 queryMembership, Int32 features)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.IdentityManagementService2.ReadFilteredIdentities(String expression, Int32 suggestedPageSize, String lastSearchResult, Boolean lookF
orward, Int32 queryMembership)
   at TFSTool.Program.GetUsers(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\dayforce\SharpTop\Build\ConfigurationManagement\utilities\tfstool\Program.cs:line 1621
   at TFSTool.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dayforce\SharpTop\Build\ConfigurationManagement\utilities\tfstool\Program.cs:line 519
```

However, if I search by just one user pattern, for example:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.Type == 'User' AND Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.DisplayName CONTAINS 'mark'
```

It works just fine.

So, my question - is it possible to search by more than one user pattern in TFS Api or am I forced to repeat the query for each pattern separately?

Comment: Where did you get Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.Type and  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.DisplayName? Could you share your whole code? When query work items in TFS, more than one user pattern is supported: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: What do you mean? I gave the exact code. The query is exactly **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.Type == 'User' AND Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity.DisplayName CONTAINS 'mark'**. The link you give does not fetch users, so it is not a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. "OR" operator is not supported by the query expression. Refer to the description for ReadFilteredIdentities() method in this article for details: [TeamFoundationIdentityService Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.teamfoundationidentityservice(v=vs.110).aspx).

> ReadFilteredIdentities is used to retrieve a set of identities based
>   on an expression. The expression is a syntax that resembles a SQL
>   WHERE clause. For details about the expressions capabilities, see the
>   documentation of the QueryExpression class. There are two parts to the
>   expression. **There are a set of values that can be used from the
>   identity and they must be AND'ed together**.